# How to extract specific information from a text file in r

Tags: r, txt

I am trying to figure out how to extract specific information from a text file in R. The text in the file looks like this:

Call:

```
lm(formula = Water ~ PeteWaterAbsMeanbyPeak[, i], data = PeteWaterAbsMeanbyPeak)
```

```
Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-3.602e-06 -1.431e-06 -1.400e-09  1.041e-06  6.586e-06 

Coefficients (from R output):

                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                 3.649e-05  9.585e-07  38.067 1.55e-15 ***
PeteWaterAbsMeanbyPeak[, i] 2.738e-03  1.418e-03   1.931    0.074 .  

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.386e-06 on 14 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2104,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.154 
F-statistic:  3.73 on 1 and 14 DF,  p-value: 0.07395
```

My goal is to extract the t value, Pr(>|t|) for each `PeteWaterAbsMeanbyPeak[, i]` as well as the associated Multiple R-squared: and Adjusted R-squared: and save them into a csv file.

How can I do that for each section in the file (as there is one for every i)?

Is this something that is possible? Would it be possible to turn the txt file into a table directly perhaps?

Comment: First save a model as an `RDS` or `RData` file and not as a text file. They you could easily load it back and extract any infomration you want.

Answer (score 0):

To extract an item from a coefficient matrix generated by a linear regression, use $coeficcient[x,y], for example:

```
summary(model)$coefficients[x,4]
```

It selects the [x,4]-th element in the "coefficient matrix". In your case, you want to extract the p-value from the intercept coefficient which is the 1st row and 4th column, so $coefficients[1,4] should do the trick.

Edit:

Just realized you wanted it for each i, and I am unsure about that. Sorry :(